# Every set has a particular property?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

It is possible to transform any set in the synthetic form?

For example, the set $A=\{0,1,2,3\}   $ can be written as $A=\{x \in \mathbb{N}\,\,|\,\,x<4\}     $

But my question not just limits to numbers, i mean any set.

Comment: What about $A=\{x \in \{0,1,2,3\}|x=x\}$?

Comment: What does synthetic form mean?

Comment: @copper.hat it means give a property to a set and thus able to discover all his elements

Comment: @Voyager: There has got to be more to it than that, for I can write $A = \{x | x \in A\}$, but that tells me nothing.

Comment: @Listing, that is also a possible notation

Comment: @copper, yes, but let's pretend we don't know A, then will be impossible to discover his elements, but if i write $A=\{x \in \mathbb{N}\,\,|\,\,x<4\}     $ then we will can

Comment: But if you are pretending that you don't know $A$, then how would you justify writing $A = \{x\in \mathbb{N} \mid x < 4\}$?  You might as well write $A = \{x\in \mathbb{Q} \mid x >22\}$.

Comment: The synthetic form of the sets is just another way to represent them, writing a open sentence to its elements must satisfy, thus not needing to write each one of its elements. To be able to write in this notation, all elements must share a property in common. But my question is: all sets have a particular property? This question is more about the definition of sets.

Comment: I see, it sounds like you want a definition of a given set $A$ that is simpler than just listing all of its elements.  I don't think this will be possible in general.  For one thing, there may be infinite sets of natural numbers that are not definable at all (they cannot be completely specified by any finite description.)  Even for finite sets, if it were always possible to find a simpler description than the one given by listing all of their elements, that would give a compression algorithm that could compress any input string, which is impossible.

Comment: @TrevorWilson, you understood my question. If you copy to answer, I will accept it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As clarified in the comments, the question is asking whether every set $A$ can be described in a way that is simpler than the trivial way of listing all the elements of $A$.

The answer to (my interpretation of this slightly vague) question is no.

Regarding finite sets, what the question is asking for would be a "guaranteed" or "perfect" compression algorithm, which is [impossible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossless_compression#Limitations).    Roughly speaking, for any fixed notion of "description" for finite sets of natural numbers (or equivalently for binary strings) there there are not enough simple descriptions available to describe all of the relevant sets.

Regarding infinite sets, the question could be construed as asking for finitary descriptions for all sets of natural numbers.  This is impossible for a similar reason; namely, that for a fixed notion of "finitary description" there are only countably many descriptions available and so Cantor's diagonalization argument can be used to find a set of natural numbers admitting no such description. (The reader should beware that this part of the answer is [subtly wrong](https://mathoverflow.net/a/44129/1682) for a certain *formalization* of the question, but this caveat does not seem relevant to the original question.)